# Unstructured data not template based to structured data

Tags: nlp, data-mining, text-mining, computer-vision

I am working on a project where my goal is to extract data from a large diversity of pdf **that does not follow a template** (i.e unstructured data not template based). My ORC part works well and now I am trying to extract data from the raw text. During my research I have mainly seen data extraction from unstructured template based data.

The only things I see for now that could work, would be to use a regex, for example, to find a date, however, I don't really know what the date is related to, or to use NER, but I don't really see how to start.

I am not limited to NLP. I can also use computer vision on the pdf or other methods.

example of input:
[image]

example of output:

```
{
date : "27/06/2019",
place : "saint-paul",
patient-name : Liliane marie SUZANNE"
patient-birthdate : "14/08/1957",
doctor : "METE",
type : "radiologie du thorax",
...
}
```

Any informations or solutions is welcome.